# Hiding tables based on current month

Tags: php, html, css

This is probably a relatively simple PHP script, but I'm at a loss after trying for a while.

I have a series of tables (see below), and I want to automatically hide the tables where the month has already passed. I'm thinking of using PHP to generate embedded CSS to achieve this. I would need a script that basically does this:

```
<?php $x=1;
do
{
echo "div.y!CURRENTYEAR!"
echo "$x;,"
$x=$x+1;
}
while ($x < CURRENTMONTH)
?>
```

I basically want the script to write out:

div.y2013 .jan, div.y2013 .feb, div.y2013 .mar

and so on, until it reaches the *current month*, so that I can then hide all the tables it just listed. I'm unsure how to take a numerical value and convert that number into a three-letter month code for this purpsoe, or maybe there's a much easier way of doing this using the various date format codes.

One thing I can't really do is modify the markup below.

```
<div class="y2013">
<table class="month jan">...data...</table>
<table class="month feb">...data...</table>
<table class="month mar">...data...</table>
...
<table class="month dec">...data...</table>
</div>

<div class="y2014">
<table class="month jan">...data...</table>
<table class="month feb">...data...</table>
<table class="month mar">...data...</table>
...
<table class="month dec">...data...</table>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried the following without success:

```
<?php 
function int2month($int)
{
   switch($int)
{
    case 1: return "jan";
    case 2: return "feb";
    case 3: return "mar";
    case 4: return "apr";
    case 5: return "may";
    case 6: return "jun";
    case 7: return "jul";
    case 8: return "aug";
    case 9: return "sep";
    case 10: return "oct";
    case 11: return "nov";
    case 12: return "nov";
    default: return "dec";
 }
}
$x=1;
do
{
    echo "div.y<?php echo date('Y'); ?>
"
    echo int2month($x).",";
    $x=$x+1;
}
while ($x < date(n))
?>
```

**EDIT: Final Code that works:**

```
<?php

function int2month($int)
{
    switch($int)
    {
         case 1: return "jan";
         case 2: return "feb";
         case 3: return "mar";
         case 4: return "apr";
         case 5: return "may";
         case 6: return "jun";
         case 7: return "jul";
         case 8: return "aug";
         case 9: return "sep";
         case 10: return "oct";
         case 11: return "nov";
         case 12:
         default: return "dec";
     }
}
$i = 1;
while ($i < date('m')):
   echo "div.y" . date('Y') . " .";
   echo int2month($i) . ", ";
   $i=$i+1;
endwhile;

echo ".place {display:none!important;}";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an easy function?

```
<?php 
function int2month($int)
{
    switch($int)
    {
        case 1: return "jan";
        //.......
        case 11: return "nov";
        case 12:
        default: return "dec";
    }
}
$x=1;
do
{
    echo "div.y!CURRENTYEAR!"
    echo int2month($x).",";
    $x=$x+1;
}
while ($x < CURRENTMONTH)
?>
```

Comment: This isn't working as I've altered it. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I've tried and pasted my results in the original post. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @Christine, I ended up altering your code a bit (while statement, instead of do while, etc.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to add a css class for the passed months via. php.

This way you can set `display: none;` to the class.

The generated html should look like this:

```
HTML:
<div class="y2013">
<table class="month jan passed">...data...</table>
<table class="month feb passed">...data...</table>
<table class="month mar passed">...data...</table>
...
<table class="month dec">...data...</table>
</div>

CSS:
.passed {display: none;}
```

---

**Edit:**

Generate the selectors with php, that you get something like this:

```
.y2012, .y2013 .jan, .y2013 .feb, .y2013 .mar, .... {dispaly: none;}
```

Comment: Thanks hugo, but unfortunately I cannot easily edit the HTML markup. It is generated by a rather complicated third-party tool, and what I didn't mention is that there are about 30 of these pages that all have the same HTML calendar markup, all kept updated by dozens of people.

Comment: @Nathan S are you able to generate a css file with php? else you would have to use javascript

Comment: I can use PHP to generate embedded CSS, so same result if I'm following you.

Comment: yeah, than you have to generate the selectors with php

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, but I'm unsure how to have PHP insert the proper months in the proper format.